# JQuery does not fetch and parse json from url

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have been developing an app to connect with an API I recently built for testing (It is working fine) but I deem to be getting an unknown error with my code. I am a newbie trying out jQuery. This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'api.lynmerc-enterprise.com/requests',
        async: false, 
        type: 'GET',
        //dataType: 'json', 
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);

            var data2 = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            console.log(data2);

            //assign parsed JSON to variables
            var apiStatus = data2.status;
            var apiMessage= data2.message;
            var apiData = data2.data; 

            var data3 = $.parseJSON(apiData);
            //Here we get Requester info and material JSON
            console.log(data3);
            var materials = data3.material;

            var data4 = $.parseJSON(materials);
            console.log(data4);

            //loop through the data and assign needed info to table
            $.each(data3, function(i,row){
                var dateRequested = data3.date;
                var projectCode = data3.p_code;
                var requestNumber = data3.rq_no;
                var materialName = data4.name;
                var purpose = data4.purpose;
                var quantity = data4.quantity;
                var cost = data4.cost;
                var total = data4.total; 
                $("table.table").append("<tr><td>"+dateRequested+"</td><td>"+projectCode+"</td><td>"+requestNumber+"</td><td>"+materialName+"</td><td>"+purpose+"</td><td>"+quantity+"</td><td>"+cost+"</td><td>"+total+"</td></tr>");
            });
        },
        //error: function(){console.log('Error Encountered')},
        beforeSend: setHeader()

    }); 
});

//set required headers
function setHeader(xhr){
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Api-Key','ZHhjZmIyMHdnazVtdWw=');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/json')
}
```

The code is supposed to connect to the API with the Api-Key as a header then fetch Json of format

```
{
    'status':success,
    'data':'[{
        "p_code":,"requester_id":,
        "date":,"rq_no":, 
        "id":, "materials":[{
            "name":,
            "purpose":,
            "cost":,
            "quantity":,
            "status":,
            "rq_no":,"id":,
            "total":},
            ...
        ]}
        .....
    ]'
```

... The data is to be assigned to variables then appended to the main HTML table

Comment: Try to use `JSON.parse(yourJsonString);`

Comment: What is the error you are getting?  Have you added a break point to the code?

Comment: It just remains blank. No Error message, Nothing...I added console.log() to help me track the progress in case of any error but it's not logging anything...The API sends a response even if the Api-Key is wrong or missing. It's just not parsing JSON

Comment: In you favorite browser: add a break point on the first line of your success handler, check it is being called, and have a look at what is being passed into it.  Also, look at the network tab in the browsers debugger.  look at the response from the server,  You should be seeing exactly the same response data passed into your success function.  Stick a break point in your `$.each(data3, function(i,row)`  see if it goes in there...

Comment: I tinkered with the code a little..setting (async:false;) was the bad idea here, but then it fetched the JSON properly I could see in the console log ..however it still returns the message "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data" which I cant seem to figure out the solution for

Comment: @CollinsAmanya it means that either your JSON is invalid, or you receive it not as a string.

Comment: @htshame I've seen the issue. it's loading  "__proto__: Object { … }" which is not part of my api response I dont know where it's coming from.

Answer (score 0):

I finally had it working perfectly:

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
            function fetchJson(){
                $(document).ready(function(){
                            $.ajax({
                            url: 'http://api.lynmerc-enterprise.com/requests',
                            headers: {
                                'Api-Key':'ZHhjZmIyMHdnazVtdWw='
                                //'Content-Type':'application/json'

                            },
                            //async: false, //return value as variable not to make an async success callback
                            type: 'GET',
                            dataType: 'json', 
                            success: function(data){
                                console.log(data);

                                //var data2 = JSON.parse(data.data);

                                var data2 = data.data;
                                var data2Array = [];

                                $.each(data2, function(idx, data2){
                                    console.log(data2.p_code);
                                    console.log(data2.date);
                                    console.log(data2.rq_no);

                                    var userfo = data2.user;
                                    console.log(userfo.fullname);
                                    console.log(userfo.project_site);

                                    var material = data2.materials;

                                    var dateRequested = data2.date;

                                    var requestNumber = data2.rq_no;

                                    var requester = userfo.fullname;

                                    var projectSite = userfo.project_site;



                                    $.each(material, function(idx, material){
                                        console.log(material.name);
                                        console.log(material.purpose);
                                        console.log(material.quantity);
                                        console.log(material.cost);
                                        console.log(material.total);
                                        console.log(material.status);

                                        var materialName = material.name;

                                        var purpose = material.purpose;

                                        var quantity = material.quantity;

                                        var cost = material.cost;

                                        var total = material.total;

                                        var requestStatus = material.status;
                                        /*$('#dateRequested').append(dateRequested);
                                        $('#requestNumber').append(requestNumber);
                                        $('#requester').append(requester);
                                        $('#projectSite').append(projectSite);
                                        $('#materialName').append(materialName);
                                        $('#purpose').append(purpose);
                                        $('#quantity').append(quantity);
                                        $('#cost').append(cost);
                                        $('#total').append(total);
                                        $('#requestStatus').append(requestStatus); */

                                        var table = $("#requestsTable");
                                    table.append("<tr><td>"+dateRequested+
                                                            "</td><td>"+requester+
                                                            "</td><td>"+projectSite+
                                                            "</td><td>"+requestNumber+
                                                            "</td><td>"+materialName+
                                                            "</td><td>"+purpose+
                                                            "</td><td>"+quantity+
                                                            "</td><td>"+cost+
                                                            "</td><td>"+total+"</td></tr>");

                                    });








                                });



                            },
                            error: function(){console.log('Error Encountered')},
                            //beforeSend: setHeader()

                        });


                    });

                /*  var request;
                    function setHeader(request){
                        request.setRequestHeader('Api-Key','ZHhjZmIyMHdnazVtdWw=');
                        request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/json')
                    }*/
                }
        </script>
```

When using dataType:'json' in the code, we dont parse the json again as jQuery does all that so when we try to parse again it returns an error. Then for it to be appended to html we use $(selector).append where the selector is the element id. In this case when appending to table, we append  to  so it will be $(#tableBodyId).append("what to append");